# JS ES6 Correct way to filter object by array of keys

Tags: javascript

I would like to take an array of objects and filter each object to only return the properties where the key matches an item in an array.

For example:

```
const myKeys    = ['key_1', 'key_3'];
const myArray   = [
    { 
        key_1: 'Some Value A',
        key_2: 'Some Other Value A', 
        key_3: 'Some Final Value A',
    },
    { 
        key_1: 'Some Value B',
        key_2: 'Some Other Value B', 
        key_3: 'Some Final Value B',
    },
    { 
        key_1: 'Some Value C',
        key_2: 'Some Other Value C', 
        key_3: 'Some Final Value C',
    },
];
```

Should produce the following result:

```
const result   = [
    { 
        key_1: 'Some Value A',
        key_3: 'Some Final Value A',
    },
    { 
        key_1: 'Some Value B',
        key_3: 'Some Final Value B',
    },
    { 
        key_1: 'Some Value C',
        key_3: 'Some Final Value C',
    },
];
```

I believe this should be possible with a combination of `.map()` and `.filter()` but I'm unsure how best to achieve the equivalent of the following using ES6:

```
const filteredData = (array, keys) => {
    const newArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        const item      = myArray[i];
        let newObj      = {};

        for (let j = 0; j < myKeys.length; j++) {
            const filter = myKeys[j];
            newObj[filter] = item[filter];
        }

        newArr.push(newObj);
    }

    return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredData(myArray, myKeys));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the wnated entries and builds objects with it.

```js
const 
    keys = ['key_1', 'key_3'],
    data = [{ key_1: 'Some Value A', key_2: 'Some Other Value A', key_3: 'Some Final Value A' }, { key_1: 'Some Value B', key_2: 'Some Other Value B', key_3: 'Some Final Value B' }, { key_1: 'Some Value C', key_2: 'Some Other Value C', key_3: 'Some Final Value C' }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply  loop over `keys` and build a new object which contains only those keys and respective values

```js
const myKeys = ['key_1', 'key_3'];
const myArray = [{key_1: 'Some Value A',key_2: 'Some Other Value A',key_3: 'Some Final Value A',},{key_1: 'Some Value B',key_2: 'Some Other Value B',key_3: 'Some Final Value B',},{key_1: 'Some Value C',key_2: 'Some Other Value C',key_3: 'Some Final Value C',},];

let final = myArray.map(v => {
  return myKeys.reduce((op, key) => {
    op[key] = v[key]
    return op
  }, {})
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myKeys    = ['key_1', 'key_3'];
const myArray   = [
 {
  key_1: 'Some Value A',
  key_2: 'Some Other Value A',
  key_3: 'Some Final Value A',
 },
 {
  key_1: 'Some Value B',
  key_2: 'Some Other Value B',
  key_3: 'Some Final Value B',
 },
 {
  key_1: 'Some Value C',
  key_2: 'Some Other Value C',
  key_3: 'Some Final Value C',
 },
];

const result = myArray.map(i => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(i).filter(([k]) => myKeys.includes(k))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `.map` each object to its entries so you can `.filter` out any entries which don't have a key in `myKeys`, and then use `.fromEntries()` to build up your new object like so:

```js
const myKeys = ['key_1', 'key_3'];
const myArray = [{
    key_1: 'Some Value A',
    key_2: 'Some Other Value A',
    key_3: 'Some Final Value A',
  },
  {
    key_1: 'Some Value B',
    key_2: 'Some Other Value B',
    key_3: 'Some Final Value B',
  },
  {
    key_1: 'Some Value C',
    key_2: 'Some Other Value C',
    key_3: 'Some Final Value C',
  },
];

const res = myArray.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => myKeys.includes(k))));

console.log(res);
```